# Metalsmith example not working on 1.0 (collections + permalinks)

Tags: javascript, static-site, metalsmith

I found an [example online](http://www.robinthrift.com/posts/metalsmith-part-2-shaping-the-metal/) which uses `collections` and `permalinks`, the code is like this:

```
Metalsmith(__dirname)
    .use(collections({
        pages: {
            pattern: 'content/pages/*.md'
        },
        posts: {
            pattern: 'content/posts/*.md',
            sortBy: 'date',
            reverse: true
        }
    }))
    .use(markdown())
    .use(permalinks({
        pattern: ':collection/:title'
    }))
    .use(templates('handlebars'))
    .destination('./build')
    .build()
```

Which converts this file structure:

```
src/
    index.md
    content/
        pages/
            aboud.md
            blog.md
        posts/
            first-post.md
```

To:

```
build/
    index.html
    content/pages/ (empty??)
    pages/
        about/ -> index.html
        blog/ -> index.html
    posts/
        first-post/ -> index.html
```

Note that `src/index.md` is converted, as well as the collections. But in `1.0.0`, the same code converts only the collections and throws an error for `index.md`: `Error: UNKNOWN, open '/home/index.html'`

Any idea?

Comment: Can you add an error callback to the `.build()` call? `function (err) { if(err) console.log(err) }` or something like that

Comment: Thanks, but I just forgot to add the callback in the question, that was not the problem. It got solved but I don't know how (!!), [here is the code](https://github.com/doup/doup.illarra.com/blob/master/gulpfile.js).

Comment: Had a similar issue with node: v0.10.29, metalsmith: v1.7.0. Started working after adding a callback as suggested for debugging by @JamesKhoury to the build() method.